# How to call a function for all views on load in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewdidload

I have a singleton and it have a function `-(void)repair;`
I can write `[Manager repair];` in every view controller in viewDidLoad, But since I have alot of view controllers I want that function to be called automatically without having to write it **manually**. 

Is That possible, or the code that required for this method is going to take longer time than calling the method in each view?

*NOTE: the reason I want to do this is to be able to enable and disable the function anytime I require without having to go back and delete it from each View.*

Comment: you cant  call the repair method like that as the repair method is not declared as class method.

Comment: AFAIK there is no shortcut unless u do some crazy hack. You have to write the code in every view did load.

Comment: @Mr.T it is part of the singleton class "Manager" which is called to every other class by importing it into prefix file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to accomplish this:

1. Create a subclass of UIViewController and implement repair in that class and have that classes viewDidLoad call self.repair. If you're using a mix of UIViewControllers, UITableViewControllers, and UICollectionView controllers, you may need to subclass each of those. Then have each of your view controllers extend the subclass rather than extending UIViewController directly. Then just make sure you're calling super.viewDidLoad in the viewDidLoad (which you should be doing anyway)
2. Method swizzle viewDidLoad, but that could get ugly pretty fast.

Comment: The first way needs to change every viewcontroller to be changed to the subclass. The second Way why it would get ugly pretty fast ?

Comment: Subclassing can have great advantage. There is usually common code across view controllers that can all be refactored into the superclass. Less code means fewer defects. My comment on swizzling is because, by it's nature, it is a bit of a cheat. One reason it would get ugly fast, is that you'd end up 'repairing' all VCs. What would happen if you made a VC that didn't need to be repaired?  Which makes me wonder, why are things needed to get repaired. Maybe instead of addressing a symptom the root cause should be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

you can swizzle UIViewController viewDidLoad method and put the repair call there.
Take a look at http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/